# How to use a Twilio function to transfer a call to a phone number with an extension?

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I'm trying to use a Twilio function to transfer a call to a phone number with an extension.

The Twilio function is called from a Twilio flow.

Right now, the call transfer to the phone number. However, the extension is never invoked.

I added some "w" characters for pause in the "sendDigits"...but it did not change anything.

[Here is my Twilio flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Auds.png)

[Here is my Twilio function widget with the parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfOGH.png)

Here is the code of the twilio function

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  // set-up the variables that this Function will use to forward a phone call using TwiML

  // REQUIRED - you must set this
  let phoneNumber = event.PhoneNumber || "NUMBER TO FORWARD TO";    
  // OPTIONAL
  let callerId =  event.CallerId || null;
  // OPTIONAL
  let timeout = event.Timeout || null;
  // OPTIONAL
  let allowedCallers = event.allowedCallers || [];

  // generate the TwiML to tell Twilio how to forward this call
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  let allowedThrough = true;
  if (allowedCallers.length > 0) {
    if (allowedCallers.indexOf(event.From) === -1) {
      allowedThrough = false;    
    }
  }

  let sendDigits = event.sendDigits;
  let dialParams = {};
  dialParams.sendDigits = sendDigits

  if (callerId) {
    dialParams.callerId = callerId;
  }
  if (timeout) {
    dialParams.timeout = timeout;
  }

  if (allowedThrough) {
    twiml.dial(dialParams, phoneNumber);
  }
  else {
    twiml.say('Sorry, you are calling from a restricted number. Good bye.');
  }

  // return the TwiML
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dial verb doesn't have a sendDigits attribute, but the REST API does.

You can use the Number noun with the Dial verb, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number, and its associated URL parameter to reference a TwiML Bin with a Play, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play, and its digits attribute, to play the DTMF after the dialed party answers the phone, but before the two parties communicate with one another.

Comment: With your feedback, I have set up a "TwiML Bin". It work great to transfer call with a phone extension (Direct Phone number association). Is there a easy way to call the "TwiML Bin" from Twilio Function or Twilio Flow. Parameter here are nice, but not mandatory.